# Can ReSharper be used when editing SSIS script tasks?

Tags: c#, ssis, resharper

I have ReSharper 6 installed and integrated with Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010. I'm editing SSIS packages in VS2008 and some of them contain script tasks. When editing the script task, a Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA) application is launched which is lacking ReSharper integration. Does anyone know if ReSharper can be installed and used in this context?

Comment: If "Visual Studio for Tools 2.0" does not contain add-in support, then it will be impossible to load ReSharper in this context.

Comment: I suppose you could just limit the SSIS scripts to calls to DLLs that you create in the full version of Visual Studio and all the Resharper goodness.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. It's a bit cumbersome, though, because I'm building those in VS2010 so there's a lot of context switching.

Comment: @SpikeX, put up your comment as an answer for me to accept. It's the best answer I've found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper works with Business Intelligence Development Studio for SQL Server 2012, primarily because SQL Server 2012 now uses the integrated Visual Studio shell for editing script files.

Anything before SQL Server 2012 does not use the integrated shell. VSTA and the isolated shell do not load additional plugins like Resharper, which is why it won't show up in BIDS for SQL Server 2008 R2 or earlier.

(In fact, the SSIS editor will create an entire temporary Visual Studio project and load it into the separate IDE as a complete, buildable solution.)

Answer (score 1):

to expand on SpikeX's answer, the Visual Studio 2008 used for SSIS is a Shell Version of Visual Studio 2008. It won't support anything beyond Business Intelligence Studio projects. (Akin to the Express version of VS2008) Since it's not a full version of VS, it can't support Resharper.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite true. The VS shell install is reused when installing a SKU with C# in. In fact, I believe you could install BIDS, ReSharper and then a VS2008 SKU containing C#. The question I asked is specific to the editor application in which the C# in script tasks is edited, i.e. VSTA.

Comment: Josh, Thanks for the correct answer vote.
I tried using ReSharper for scripting in SSIS Tasks and it didn't work no matter what I did. Just tried to give a slightly more intelligent (and reasoned) answer than "it didn't work on my machine"